# Compare ArrayList entry with the next ArrayList entry

Tags: java

I want to compare the first ArrayList entry with the second one. The second one with the thirt one and so one. The comparison should be that the second entry that should be compared has to be higher than the first one.

I wrote the following code:

```java
for (double x : Test2) // my ArrayList is called Test2
{
    if (x < x + 1) // for example compare entry one with entry one+1, that makes entry two (i think atleast)
    {
        variable3 = true;       
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't use the for-each syntax, as you need two items of the list at the same time. Use `for(var i = 0, j=Test2.size()-1; i<j; i++) { var c1 = Test2.get(i); var c2 = Test2.get(i+i); ...` and compare c1 to c2

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var values = asList(1, 2, 3, 4);

for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    if (i < values.size()-1) {
        var current = values.get(i);
        var next = values.get(i+1);

        //TODO do your logik
        boolean isNextHigher = next > current;
    }
}
```